# Cleansing flat file with Python and Regex - random records are broken into partial records due to faulty CRLFs

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, data-cleaning, flat-file

I'm working on cleansing a pipe-delimited flat file and have been stuck on an issue where I have random CRLF's throughout the file that are breaking valid records (with 24 expected delimiters) into partial records across subsequent rows.

The location of these CRLFs appear to be relatively random and the number of these CRLFs per record vary. Here's an example:

**Here's what I'm seeing (using a simpler 3 delimiter example):**

```
this|is|a|test
don't|be
alarmed|
if|there
is|a|broken|record
above|this|is|expected
```

You can see that the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th rows are all partial records that should be a single records with 3 expected delimiters.

**Here's what I'd expect to see / what I'm trying to produce:**

```
this|is|a|test
don't|be alarmed|if|there
is|a|broken|record
above|this|is|expected
```

My aim with this part of the cleansing is to:

1. Identify all records that do not have the expected number of delimiters (due to faulty CRLFs)
2. Collapse those records into a single complete record with the expected number of delimiters (by removing the faulty CRLFs)

I'm doing this primarily in a Jupyter notebook. Below is the one approach that's showing promise so far.

**Here's my approach:**

1. Identify rows that: do not have 24 delimiters ***and*** are not followed
   by a row with 24 delimiters

   - Do so with the following regex:
     `^(?!(.*?\|){24}).*\n(?!(.*?\|){24}.*\n)`
   - (the rationale for the second part of the above is to ignore the last row of the partial record, so we don't wind up messing up the subsequent good row with our replace below)
2. Then I can use the re.sub() function to replace '\n' with ' ' for those rows

[This has worked with the small 3-delimiter sample data](https://regex101.com/r/5PEJWN/1) I showed in the above example, but at scale my regex fails due to 'catastrophic backtracking'. In fact, it fails due to catastrophic backtracking even with a 6 record sample of real data.

Any thoughts or recommendations on either improving my regex to avoid catastrophic backtracking or any other suggestions for how to solve this kind of CRLF issue.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the file line by line, check the count of `|`s, and if the count is less than X, keep the row, read the next one, append to the existing row data, check the count, repeat if necessary, once the count is X, write the line to the fixed file.

Comment: How are you parsing the file? Post your code. CSV files actually *allow* newlines in quoted fields. Instead of trying to "fix" the file, you should probably modify the code to handle newlines in fields if possible.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps you should fix the code that generates the flat file, and ensure the text fields are quoted. I suspect you use `|` instead of `,` as a delimiter because in your locale `,` is the decimal separator.